# How to parse Web page with dynamic web content in java?

Tags: parsing, dynamic

i want to parse a HTML page which contains some values displayed.That values are updated at regular intervals.I have to get that value from a standalone java program.If i parse the HTML page with some HTML parser the source of that page is displayed instead of that value.i tried with NEkoHTML parser and JTidy parser but there are not the right parsers for my task.If any body having idea about this please help me.

Comment: What are you trying to do?Do you want to retrieve the updated values? If yes, just retrieve the values using jQuery and pass it to a java function.

Comment: The HTML page gets data from one server at regular time intervals through some script language if i parse the page means it gives the script code not that value.In this case what i have to do.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is determine if a value is dynamic and if it is, don't grab the value, but the code that generates the value.

If the value is generated using server-side code, you aren't able to do what you want. If it's generated with client-side code (such as JavaScript), you could start parsing through the files to determine what calls are made on certain events and actions, but it's a non-trivial task.

Comment: Its a client side script(JavaScript) only.But i am beginner of javascript so please can you provide some simple code or any other source to learn parings the java script code.

Comment: @Rajapandian: let us be clear. Java and Javascript are completely different languages.  Which one are you talking about?